# How to generate matrix in MATLAB where values decrease with increasing coordinates

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to generate an n x n matrix like

```
5 4 3 2 1
4 4 3 2 1
3 3 3 2 1
2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

where n = 5 or n  50. I'm at an impasse and can only generate a portion of the matrix. It is Problem 2.14 from Numerical Methods using MATLAB 3rd Edition by Penny and Lindfield. This is the best I have so far:

```
n = 5;
m = n;
A = zeros(m,n);

for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        A(i,j) = m;
    end
    m = m - 1;    
end
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a nice brain-teaser, here’s my solution:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(5:-1:1);
out = min(x,y)
```

Output:

```
ans =

     5     4     3     2     1
     4     4     3     2     1
     3     3     3     2     1
     2     2     2     2     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one loop-based approach:

```
n = 5;
m = n;
A = zeros(m, n);
for r = 1:m
  for c = 1:n
    A(r, c) = n+1-max(r, c);
  end
end
```

And here's a vectorized approach (probably not faster, just for fun):

```
n = 5;
A = repmat(n:-1:1, n, 1);
A = min(A, A.');
```

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the matrices in Matlab's [`gallery`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html), except that it needs a 180-degree rotation, which you can achieve with [`rot90`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html):

```
n = 5;
A = rot90(gallery('minij', n), 2);
```